# GCC gives incorrect answer with optimization enabled

Tags: c, gcc

I have the following C program

```
double d = 1.4;
int x;
x = d * 10;
printf("\n\n VALUE = %d " ,x);
```

I have gcc 4.3.3 which comes with Ubuntu 9.04

I get answer as 13 with -O0 but get correct answer i.e 14 with higher levels of optimization

Is this a known issue or something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 9):

You can't represent 1.4 exactly using `double`, the value is actually a bit lagrer or a bit smaller (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)). So there is no "correct" answer - use `round()` instead of implictly truncating.

Answer (score 9):

This is gcc [bug #323](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=323) , in reality this is not a bug but an implementation detail.

Answer (score 4):

At higher levels of optimization, GCC probably optimizes both variables away and precomputes the value to print. At no optimization, the value of `d` (and thus the printing value) will be subject to floating point representation, and may not be exactly `1.4`. Try this:

```
double d = 1.4;
int x;
x = d * 10;
printf("Old = %lf, New = %d\n", d, x);
```

Answer (score 2):

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

It really is what the title says, and it also applies to programmers in general.